# SOQL Query Limit

Tags: soql, query, governorlimits

What does this statement  from the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) document mean?

> In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship subqueries, each parent-child relationship counts as an extra query. These types of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level queries. The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row counts of the overall code execution.

I tried:

```
List<Trail__c> records = [select Id,(select Id,type,Industry from Accounts__r) from trail__c]
```

but it shows only one query fired in `Limit.getQueries()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A parent-child subquery is counted as an "Aggregate" query, which, despite the name, has nothing to do with [SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

The wording in the documentation is...not the clearest here. In a single transaction, you can have up to 300 parent-child subqueries. Each row returned by a parent-child subquery *does count* towards the 50,000 query row governor limit.

A subquery doesn't show up in `Limit.getQueries();` as you've seen. Instead, you need to use `Limits.getAggregateQueries();`